# Julia - linear regression - ERROR: DimensionMismatch

Tags: dataframe, julia

I wish to do a linear regression in Julia, but I am getting an error: 
DimensionMismatch("column length 3000 for column(s) X, and is incompatible with column length 1000 for column(s) Y")

```
julia> x=rand(1000,3);

julia> x[:,1]=x[:,1] .+ 1;

julia> y = rand(1000,1) .+ 3;

julia> size(x)
(1000, 3)

julia> size(y)
(1000, 1)

julia> ols = lm(@formula(Y ~ X), DataFrame(X = x, Y = y))
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("column length 3000 for column(s) X, and is incompatible with column length 1000 for column(s) Y")
Stacktrace:
 [1] (::getfield(DataFrames, Symbol("##DataFrame#83#86")))(::Bool, ::Type, ::Array{Any,1}, ::DataFrames.Index) at /Users/henry/.julia/packages/DataFrames/CZrca/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:118
 [2] Type at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [3] #DataFrame#94(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Symbol,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{Symbol,Symbol},NamedTuple{(:X, :Y),Tuple{Array{Float64,2},Array{Float64,2}}}}, ::Type) at /Users/henry/.julia/packages/DataFrames/CZrca/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:174
 [4] (::getfield(Core, Symbol("#kw#Type")))(::NamedTuple{(:X, :Y),Tuple{Array{Float64,2},Array{Float64,2}}}, ::Type{DataFrame}) at ./none:0
 [5] top-level scope at none:0
```

Can someone help?

Comment: You need to make both `x` and `y` of  the same size. So their size should be `(1000, 3)` or `(1000,1)`

Comment: @philoez98 they are of the same size: I display the sizes above.

Comment: They're not, (1000,3) is not equal (1000,1), that's why you get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when you write:

```
DataFrame(X = x, Y = y)
```

You are trying to set `Matrix` as a column of a `DataFrame`. This is not allowed. You can only add vectors as columns of a data frame. So this will work for example

```
DataFrame([x y], [:x1, :x2, :x3, :y])
```

So in your original code you can write for example:

```
lm(@formula(y ~ x1+x2+x3), DataFrame([x y], [:x1, :x2, :x3, :y]))
```